# Toggle live preview in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am using jquery adapter for ckeditor, I am able to add custom css files in editor preview using `CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss` 
Below is embedded javascript code to create ckeditor for textarea with #editor2 ID.

```
jQuery(function()
{
  var config = {
  contentsCss :['css/bootsrap/bootstrap.css', 'contents-custom.css'],
}
jQuery('#editor2').ckeditor(config);
```

I want to create a plugin which may be call "live preview" on click of this button these CSS files will be added.  This button should be like toggle.

My question is, How can I control the config from adding and deleting contentCss configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery, you'll be able to trick the page. I don't think there's a known way for doing that with CKEditor's API. But, you can delete the `<link>` your files.

```
//to remove styling:
$('#cke_ckeditor iframe').contents().find('html head link').remove();
//to reload CSS:
$('#cke_ckeditor iframe').contents().find('html head').append('<link href="customContents.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
```

If you want, you can control which file will be removed by removing only the `first()` or the `last()` link, as well in the reloading snippet.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Nadav, but selector can not find html head in iframe.

Comment: @WasimShaikh can you provide a link or paste your code? Does the selector find `#cke_editor` and the IFRAME but not the head element? Try removing `html` from the selector